# Update only Y axis - CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I have a CanvasJS chart in which my X axis is static (example below)

[image: Example chart]

I would like to dynamically update only the Y axis so that the value for each area is updated live as the user views the graph (i.e. if Area 1 was to become 20 instead of 10 the graph would update to reflect this.)

Below is my code I have so far for adding and updating data. Just now, when the update function is called, the graph will not have the updated Y axis added if a change has been made but the X axis is duplicated.

**Code:**

```
function addData(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({
            label: data[i].area,
            y: data[i].number
        });
    }
    chart.render();
setTimeout(function(){updateYAxis(data)}, 5000);
}

function updateYAxis(data) {
  console.log("Update called");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataPoints.push({
      label: data[i].authority,
      y: data[i].attendanceRows
    });
  }
  setTimeout(function(){$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/implementation/data/overflow.json", updateYAxis)}, 5000);
  chart.render();
}
```

**Output on screen after update:**

[image: Update example]

How can i edit my code to update only the Y axis as changes are made to the data?

Example data:

```
[
  {
    "area": "Area 1",
    "number": 10
  },
  {
    "area": "Area 2",
    "number": 15
  },
  {
    "area": "Area 3",
    "number": 7
  },
  {
    "area": "Area 4",
    "number": 24
  }
]
```

**Edit:**
I have added JsFiddle as requested:

https://jsfiddle.net/8qf1Lk3c/

Comment: please share a codepen or a fiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: Hi, I've added a fiddle link at the bottom @DhananjaiPai